# Mean coordinates from several columns

Tags: qgis, coordinates, column, mean, weighted

I have a delimited text layer created from table with a few hundred coordinates (lat/long) in columns A and B and several hundred values associated with these coordinates in columns C to XXX. Now, I would like to create mean coordinates for each column from C to XXX - weighted by the values in the given column.

[image: Columns in table (section)]

Manually, I can create these mean coordinates in QGIS 3.16.14 (LTR) via "Processing Toolbox"/"Mean coordinate(s"): I choose the delimited text layer as input layer and select a column via "Weight field". This works fine. However, I would have to do this individually for every column. And this would a few days.

Is there an easy way to automatize this process? One "mean coordinate" per column C to XXX? The expected result would be a "line" of points on the map, one "mean coordinate" for every column, for example like this:

[image]

I tried "Run as Batch Process" in the toolbox but I still would have to select every column manually...

How can this workflow be automated? Any ideas?

SAMPLE DATA (for a semicolon CSV):

```
lat;lon;97;98;99;100;101;102;103;104;105;106;107;108;109;110;111
54.65455;19.90929;1000;1480;1960;2440;2920;3400;3880;4360;4840;5320;5800;6280;6760;7240;7720
54.36346;12.72491;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
54.41823;13.43349;500;600;;;;;;;;;;;;;
56.87930;16.65634;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
53.42894;14.55302;;;;;;;;11700;11600;11500;11400;11300;11200;11100;11000
59.43696;24.75353;;7072;7143;7215;7286;7358;7429;7500;7572;7643;7715;7786;7858;7929;8000
57.64089;18.29602;;;;;;;;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000
55.00801;11.91057;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
60.70763;28.75283;;;;;;;;;;;1160;1200;1240;1280;1320
54.17670;12.08402;3000;3250;3500;3750;4000;4100;4200;4300;4400;4500;4600;4700;4800;4900;5000
53.89314;11.45286;;;;;;;;1000;1000;2000;3000;4000;6000;8000;9000
63.82842;20.25972;;;;;;;;1000;1005;1013;950;1000;1000;1000;1000
53.87537;13.92394;;;;;;;;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000
54.58048;16.86194;;;;;;;;1226;1259;;;;;;
59.66755;28.28713;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
60.80043;21.40841;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000
63.09600;21.61577;;;;;;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000
57.75840;16.63733;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1100;1200;1300;1400;1500;1600;1700;1800;1900;2000
57.39485;21.56121;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
55.09510;10.24226;;;;;;;;;;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000
54.78431;09.43961;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
55.56568;09.75257;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2100;2200;2300;2400;2500;2600;2700;2800;2900;3000
54.35766;19.68029;;;;;;;;;678;;;;;;
60.67452;17.14174;;;;;;;;;8334;8250;8167;8084;8000;7917;7834
54.35227;18.64912;;;;;;;;3260;3297;3334;3371;3408;3445;3482;3519
54.51889;18.53188;;;;;;;;420;430;440;450;460;470;480;490
54.26698;18.95196;;;;;;;;;;;2000;2158;2316;2474;2632
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And sorry if I wasn't clear here!

I calculate the mean coordinate for every column (C to XXX) from the coordinates given in the columns A and B.

Comment: Thus, every mean coordinate is calculated by dozens of coordinates, weighted by the values of the given columns (C to XXX).

Comment: Run `Mean Coordinate(s)` in Batch mode: click at the lower left of the dialog window

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Dear Babel,
Thanks. I tried "Batch Processing". However, it seems I have to add (via "+") rows for all my columns manually. And then, I have to select all the columns C to XXX in "Weight field" manually. How does "Autofill" work? "Fill down" adds the same column again and again...

Not as automated as I hoped...

Comment: You can create an expression that automatically creates and fills in all the fields you want. Can't see how to do right now, hope to have some time tomorrow. Maybe there's another solution till then.

Comment: OK, thanks. I appreciate your help very much!

An example for such an expression would be great (see my sample data above). This would help me very much. I'll check the thread tomorrow.

Comment: Btw, what's the difference between "Calculate by expression" and "Add values by expression"? Both direct to the "Expression string builder".

Comment: Would be great to have this sample data as a file - can you share it? Otherwise i have to type all these values.  By the way: there are many empty cells. Should these entries be ignored?

Comment: Yes, I can provide you with an samplefile.

Comment: I have a CSV.
And yes, the empty entries should be ignored.

Comment: I pasted sample data for a semicolon separated CSV into my original post.

Comment: What do you mean by `XXX`. Is it an actual column name? If so, it means there are thousands of columns, right?

Comment: XXX was just a placehodler. There are just a few hundred columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following script. It adds all results to one layer.

- Add CSV to QGIS.
- Select the layer and run the script.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

crs = layer.crs().authid()
uri = "Point?crs=" + crs + "&field=field:string&field=MEAN_X:double&field=MEAN_Y:double&index=yes"
mean_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'TEST', 'memory')

fields = layer.fields().names()[2:]
features = list(layer.getFeatures())

for field in fields:
    weighted_xs = []
    weighted_ys = []
    weights = []
    for f in features:
        weight = f[field] if f[field] != NULL else 1.0
        p = f.geometry().asPoint()
        weighted_xs.append(p.x() * weight)
        weighted_ys.append(p.y() * weight)
        weights.append(weight)
    
    feat = QgsFeature(mean_layer.fields())
    feat["field"] = field
    mx = sum(weighted_xs) / sum(weights)
    my = sum(weighted_ys) / sum(weights)
    feat["MEAN_X"] = mx
    feat["MEAN_Y"] = my
    
    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(mx, my))
    feat.setGeometry(geom)
    
    mean_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mean_layer)
```

**Result**:

[image]

**Attribute Table**: (Field names are added as `field` value)

[image]

Comment: Addin all to one layer - maybe even better!

Comment: @Babel I guess, there are thousands of columns. In Excel, `C` to `XXX` means that. `A` to `ZZZ` equals `26+26*26+26*26*26)`.

Comment: As stated above: XXX was just a (poorly chosen) placeholder. Sorry for this misunderstanding. There are just a few hundred columns.

Comment: The script works fine! Thanks again! Just one question: The script does only work with INTEGER values, but not with FLOAT values. Is there an alternative to the operator "*" that works with floating-point numbers?

Comment: Not tested, but try `weight = float(f[field]) if f[field] != NULL else 1.0`

Answer (score 3):

### Solution: Use batch mode

Run `Mean Coordinate(s)` in Batch mode: click at the lower left of the dialog window.

To automatically fill the `Weight field` in the dialog for each attribute, insert an array of the corresponding fieldnames clicking `Autofill... / Add values by Expression...` like this:

```
array('val1','val2','val3','val4','val5')
```

Then for every element of the array (fieldname), a new row will be generated and the tool runs separately for each row - see screenshots below.

---

### Automatically create an array of all fieldnames

Edit: You can create the array of field names automatically - handy if you have hundreds of fieldnames to include. Here the expression (with the help of @MrXsquared, see comments) to use. This gets you all fieldnames of the layer `points` (end of line 2), except the fieldnames excluded in line 3:

```
array_filter (
    map_akeys(attributes(get_feature_by_id('points',1))),
    @element not in ('fid','lat','lon', 'fields')
)
```

[image]

*Output of the tool in batch mode for the sample dataset you provided: the colored points inside the red line are the weighted mean coordinates for each of the attribute values (97 to 111):*
[image]

Comment: Reading your answer i slowly (but still not entirely) get the question. May I suggest to use something like `map_akeys(attributes(get_feature_by_id('layername',1)))` to auto get an array of all fieldnames, that avoids typing all hundreds of names by hand.

Comment: @MrXsquared - that's what I was trying for some time in different variants, however, it does not work. Somehow the layer is not identified and no attributes are returned. Would be interesting to see if there is a way to achieve this. Workaround: create a list of attribute names on the layer itself, copy the result and paste it to the batch mode expression editor. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: You're right - I overlooked the `attributes(feature)` variant - just hat `attributes()` in view (I knew that it should work somehow). Maybe worth adding as another answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas and suggestions! Very instructive and much to think about. I did not know about this possibility to automatically create an array of all fieldnames. That's very helpful, not only in this context.

Comment: The script works fine! Thanks again!

Just one question: The script does only work with INTEGER values, but not with FLOAT values. Is there an alternative to the operator "*" that works with floating-point number?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry!